# Committing docker image for jenkins with configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins, commit

1. I started docker container with jenkins.
2. Then configured it the way I need.
3. And then commmited new docker image to be able start it on other machine easily.

**But** when I start new container from this updated image, my configuration got erased and I see only welcome screen instead of my environment.

Is there an easy way to solve it? 
I used official image [for jenkins.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)